# Auto Populate a SharePoint list item based on the value of a column from a different list

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow, infopath2010

Basically what I need is User selects an item from a drop down. That value creates a list item in a separate list using values from the first list. So List A user selects value hits submit then new item creates with values from List A to List B. I only have access to Infopath 2010 and SharePoint designer 2010.

(A little back story on what i'm doing) I currently utilize Infopath to switch views based on values and i use SharePoint to view each item in multiple dashboards. It worked great until the number of dashboards grew and the sheer amount of validations are tripping over each other. Also it's bogging down load times. I've run out of tricks to make it stable. I was initially led to believe this would be a 4 or 5 dashboard "workflow" but then when the 8th and 9th one started being requested to all communicate together with 19 dashboards planned i realized this should have been done differently in the beginning. Hindsight not being 20/20 and all.

I believe this can be done with SharePoint workflow but not sure on the right steps to do it, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a workflow using Sharepoint designer. create a list workflow in list A, make sure thick the run on item added. This function will do exactly what you want. "Copy item in Current Item to List B". [detailed steps](http://blogs.salmanghani.info/copy-item-workflow-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/)